# Web Components - Using <slot> to fill in text with no tags

Tags: html, web-component

Consider the following HTML and JS

```js
customElements.define("my-comp", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let template = document.getElementById('my-template');
    let templateContent = template.content;

    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    shadowRoot.appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
  <style>
    span {
      border: 1px solid red
    }
  </style>
  
  <template id="my-template">
        I'm a new custom component using slots with value <slot name="slot1">default</slot>
  </template>

  <my-comp>
    <span slot="slot1">slotted value</span>
  </my-comp>
  
  <p> </p>
  
  <my-comp>
    <n slot="slot1">without span</n>
  </my-comp>
  
</html>
```

This will allow my page to show a `<my-comp>` with the inner HTML being my template text and then a `<span>` element containing my slotted in value of `slotted value`.

However, if the document had say a global CSS styling on `<span>`, I would see that styling on my inserted slotted value, when the template intended it to be just a string.

How might I be able to add just a text string without any CSS rules potentially applying to it? Currently I'm using an invalid element name `<n>` to get around the issue.

Comment: Please use the [<>] button in the StackOverflow editor, and make your code into a executing SO snippet. Including the ``<n>`` tag you mention.

Answer (score 0):

`<slot>` are styled by the **container** element, *not* (necessarily) by **global CSS**

In your example that was the global DOM:

```
<style>
<web-component>
  <span slot="slot1">
  --shadowRoot
    <slot name="slot1"> // styled by <style>
```

If you want to protect your `<span>`; you have to add one extra `shadowRoot`

```
<style>
<web-component>
  --shadowRoot
    <span slot="slot1">
      --shadowRoot
        <slot name="slot1"> // NOT styled by <style>
```

Note how I moved the `<span>` **inside** the first shadowRoot.

In the example below I used `<div>` instead of `<span>` for easier layout"
Also note where I added an **extra** `<style>`, because `<slot>` are styled by its **container** element

The Web Component creates **two** shadowRoots;
and **MOVES** the `<style> and <div>` elements inside the first shadowRoot
using: `container.append(...this.children);`

But the `this.children` are only available when the **whole** `<my-comp>` is parsed;
that is why a `setTimeout` is required

```html
<style>
    div { border: 2px solid green }
</style>
<template id="my-template">
  <div>
    Web Component with <b>reflected</b> content: <slot name="slot1">default</slot>
  </div>
</template>

<div>Web Component with an extra shadowRoot:</div>
<my-comp>
  <!-- this content is "moved down" one shadowRoot -->
  <style>
    div { color: red /* styles slot within this <my-comp> */ }
  </style>
  <div slot="slot1"><h2>Forget R18! Web Components rule!</h2></div>
</my-comp>

<script>
  customElements.define("my-comp", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode:'open'});
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // wait till innerHTML is parsed
        let container = document.createElement("span");
        this.shadowRoot.append(container);
        container.append(...this.children);
        container.attachShadow({mode:'open'})
                 .append(document.getElementById('my-template').content.cloneNode(true));
      });
    }
  })
</script>
```

Also note you might want to work with extra `<template>` tags because that extra `<style>` tag I added will style the **global DOM** for as long it is not moved **yet** to a shadowRoot... causing FOUCs.
But that would have complicated the above example.

Comment: Hey @Danny, just following up on this. You don't see a way to slot in text strings without tags? I can only see unnamed slots being able to take in text strings, but fundamentally I'll need to use some tag name to pass in slot attribute.

Comment: Since `n` is not used as a tag name and isn't a valid custom component name, I suppose using that works?